# Keyword Search for a comment in group wall

Tags: facebook, search, comments, facebook-groups

How do I search for a comment I made on a Facebook group wall post a long time ago?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps given below:

1. Visit your Facebook Timeline:
2. Click on "Activity Log". Here is a screenshot to make it easier for you to find it:

[image: A Screenshot from the new facebook timeline, showing the Settings, Activity Log and Update info buttons]

3. Scroll down to your heart's content until you think that you have scrolled down enough.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on your Keyboard.
5. Type the keyword you want to search for.

P.S: The activity log is only available with Timeline and not otherwise. If you no longer have access to the posts of the particular group (group admin blocked you from group; it's a closed group and you are no longer a member); then you will not be able to view/delete the comment.

Comment: That’s not going to work; the content of the page is dynamically loaded, so even if you search the page with `Ctrl+F`, if it’s not yet loaded, you won’t find it.

Comment: @Alex That why I said, "Scroll Down to your Heart's Content until you think that you have scrolled down enough."

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Facebook Group.
2. Click on magnifying glass icon on top right to search this group:
   [image]
3. Enter your name. You should see all posts by you and all posts where you made a comment.