# How do I search for posts in a Facebook group?

Tags: search, facebook-groups

[How do I search for posts in a group?](https://www.facebook.com/help/124679047612553?helpref=uf_permalink) tells me to *click Search this group in the top right*. But that option is gone.

There was a magnifying glass (from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58082/35071), but it's not showing anymore:

[image]

Is it still possible to search for posts/ content inside FB groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has moved from *Right Top side* to the **bottom of the Left Side bar Menu Items**, but based on normal screen size, it will typically show in the middle of your PC screen.

PS: Answer is courtesy and thanks to the comment from @pnuts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't...since they moved the search window to the left, there aren't any options to search for words 'inside' the posts. So you can search the initial writing (if any) at the top, but that's it. No more searching for comments.